# plots to folder python

Tags: python, plot, savefig

I am having issue saving plots to a folder. I want to store all of the plots created in a for loop to a folder that I previously created.

I tried using `imsave()` function as follows:

```py
for p in samples:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.boxplot([group1[p], group2[p], group3[p]])
    ax.set_xticklabels(["group1", "group2", "group3"])
    ax.set_ylabel("mean")
    plt.show()
    plt.imsave('/Users/.../Desktop/.../folder', ax)
```

But it does not save any plot to the folder, it just prints last plot and another one with all of the plots on it. I also tried using savefig() but also did not manage to save plots to my folder.

Additionally, it would be perfect if each plot had a name for example `plot_p` where `p` changes in a for loop, so I tried this:

```py
plt.savefig("/Users/.../Desktop/.../folder/plot_{p}.png")
```

which gave me an error that more than 20 plots want to be opened (which is a good sign) but just 1 is saved in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to change the order of plt.savefig() and plt.show() or just remove it. Try the following

```
for p in range(num):
    x = np.random.rand(num) #random code
    y = np.random.rand(num) #random code
    z = np.random.rand(num) #random code
    plt.boxplot([x,y,z]) #ploting
    plt.xticks([1,2,3],["group1", "group2", "group3"]) #plotting
    plt.savefig(f"/Users/.../Desktop/.../folder/name_you_wish_plot_to_have_{p}")
```

Comment: And as name in plt.savefig(f"name_{p}") should I put the desired folder path or the name of the plot (but then how does it know that it has to be saved in this exact folder?) ?

Comment: f"/Users/.../Desktop/.../folder/name_you_wish_plot_to_have_{p}". I belive if the same name is used the plot will be overwritten.

Comment: I have just tried it and it just saves 1 plot in the folder (with the name I put and number, so the p worked) and prints also just 1 and another one again with every plot on one image.

Comment: could you post an image?

Comment: Added to the post. I tried adding plt.close() at the end of the code in the for loop, but the same result

Comment: Ok- it works now! I deleted the plt.show() and added plt.close() instead. Thanks for your help!

Comment: nice :) was just about to edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

```py
for p in samples:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.boxplot([group1[p], group2[p], group3[p]])
    ax.set_xticklabels(["group1", "group2", "group3"])
    ax.set_ylabel("mean")
    plt.savefig(f"/Users/.../Desktop/.../folder/name_{p}")
    plt.close()
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74969330/6) to the question [plots to folder python [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74969330/plots-to-folder-python-solved) by the OP [barista](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20183885/barista) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>